# Reciprocal of cos(x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given the following development:

[image]

Focusing on the first part: $\cos(x)\sin(x)$

Dividing by $\sin(x)$ gives $\cos(x)$

Shouldn't the reciprocal be $1/\cos(x)$ as opposed to $\cos(x)$?

Comment: Note that if $a>b$, $a,b \neq 0$ and $a, b$ have the same sign, that then $1/a < 1/b$. In other words the $1/\cos$ is the term at the end, as all inequalities have switched.

Comment: Oh right... So the order changed... if you want to write that up I'll accept it....

Comment: Be careful that all these passages hold roughly only if everything is positive, for instance when $x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\sin(x) \cos(x) ≤ x ≤ \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

for $x>0$ near enough to zero, you can divide out $\sin$ when it is positive to get

$$\cos(x) ≤ \frac{x}{\sin(x)} ≤ \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$

Note that everything is positive, so inverting reverses all inequalities

$$\frac1{\cos(x)}≥\frac{\sin(x)}x≥\cos(x)$$